# How to get current session with only the SID?

Tags: google-app-engine, session, gae-sessions

How can I retrieve a session using only its session identifier (SID)? I'm using [gae-sessions](http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki).

Update for response @David Underhill:

I've done what you suggested, but in debug mode I got this:
`Session: SID=None {} |` but it has `db_key` populated with a string.

Here is my code:

**upload.py**

```
SID = self.request.get("SID")
if not SID:
return False

from app.models.user import User
user = User.get_current_user(SID)
```

**user.py**

```
def get_current_user(SID = None):
    if SID:
        session = Session(sid=SID)
    else:
        session = get_current_session()

    if session.has_key('account.logged'):
        return User.get(db.Key(session.get('user.key')))
    else:
        return False
```

and doesn't exists.

And this is my SID from my cookie:

> "mMumLZOCq5knTg9edaSjLD+p8xsSohAQSS9vyqpgDso=1289155992_9c2c85c6931a7d133f7e1f0b9ae25502gAJ9cQB9cQEoVQ5hY2NvdW50LmxvZ2dlZHECiFUIdXNlci5rZXlxA1UjYWd0MGIzUjBlWE4zYjNKc1pISUxDeElFVlhObGNoaTNBUXdxBFULYWNjb3VudC5rZXlxBVUnYWd0MGIzUjBlWE4zYjNKc1pISU9DeElIUVdOamIzVnVkQmkyQVF3cQZVDWFjY291bnQuZW1haWxxB1UBdHEIdYZxCS4="

I take this from cookies, with JavaScript and Flex, then send it in a variable to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve a session used only its SID, directly instantiate the `Session` class:

```
session = gaesessions.Session(sid="SID of the session you want")
```

If you want to retrieve a session using only its session ID, then that session *must* have been persisted to the datastore or memcache.  By default, [gae-sessions](http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki) only stores small sessions in secure cookies which are much faster than either memcache or the datastore.

To force a particular session to be saved to the datastore, you can call `save(persit_even_if_using_cookie=True)` on the session object.  This will force it to be stored to the datastore/memcache even if it normally would only be stored in a cookie.  This is the best approach if you only need to occasionally access user sessions by SID alone.

If you need to frequently access sessions by SID, then you might be better off disabling the cookie-only mechanism by passing `cookie_only_threshold=0` to the `SessionMiddleware` when you configure it - this will ensure that cookies are never used and that your sessions are always in the datastore.

These details and more are documented more thoroughly in the [gae-sessions documentation](http://dound.com/myprojects/gae-sessions/docs/html/docindex.html).

Comment: check out the update in my question. still doesn't work :s
I can only try next the cookie_only_threshold=0

Comment: After you do the `save(persit_even_if_using_cookie=True)` the session should appear in the datastore.  Can you manually query the datastore to see if the session is there?  (It should be the only one if you typically use cookie-only sessions).  Good thought setting dirty=True (only required if you haven't changed anything in your session - since you set user.key, you don't need to set dirty).

Comment: yes, I check in the datastore viewer and exits. I really don't understand why I still can't get my session by sid.. :s

Comment: Strange; this works for me.  Could you perhaps post a small code sample which illustrates the issue?  (Or your whole project if you're okay with sharing and don't want to factor out a small sample)

Comment: Great, glad you were able to fix it.