# gae-sessions: semantics of retrieving sessions by ID

Tags: google-app-engine

```
session = get_current_session()
a1 = session.has_key('account.logged') # is true
session2 = Session(sid=session.sid)
a2 = session2.has_key('account.logged') # is false
```

why a2 is not equal to a1?

solution: it must be saved to datastore:
[How to get current session with only the SID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060106/gae-sessions-how-to-get-current-session-with-with-only-the-sid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.  Retrieving a session by session ID (SID) requires that the session be stored on the server (either in memcache or the datastore).  By default, [gae-sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki) *only* stores the session in a secure client-side cookie.  This is much faster than storing it to the datastore or even memcache (see the performance comparison section at the bottom of [this article](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki/comparison-with-alternative-libraries)).

If you want to retrieve a session by SID, then you have to force the session to be stored on the server.  You can do this by either turning off cookie-only sessions (only recommended if you need to retrieve by SID often) or by forcing a particular session to be stored server-side (by passing [`persist_even_if_using_cookie=True` to `save()`](http://dound.com/myprojects/gae-sessions/docs/html/docindex.html#gaesessions.Session.save)).  More details [here](http://groups.google.com/group/gae-sessions/browse_thread/thread/93886851a987d01f).

Comment: "By default, gae-sessions only stores the session in a secure client-side cookie." I have my doubts, but how secure is it? I don't trust nothing on client.